# Why does update set work but not inc?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code, when I call $set it overwrites my data 
with the correct information for the correct user.

works:

```
$coll1->update(array("_id"=>$pid),array('$set' => array("balance" => $credit)));
```

However, when I want to increase nothing happens.

does not work:

```
$coll1->update(array("_id"=>$pid),array('$inc' => array("balance" => $credit)));
```

Based on the documentation they should follow the same pattern:

```
$inc

{ $inc : { field : value } }
```

increments field by the number value if field is present in the object, otherwise sets field to the number value. This can also be used to decrement by using a negative value.

```
$set

{ $set : { field : value } }
```

sets field to value. All datatypes are supported with $set.

Comment: what type of value (in MongoDB) is the "balance" field? `$inc` only works for numbers

Comment: Are you certain $credit contains a number (and not some other data type)?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I initialize the default object like this : "balance" => 0. Is it possible that the php variable $credit is considered a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, here's a [quick gist](https://gist.github.com/217cef5f3dea1b802d6b) that demonstrates the code working correctly.

There are two things to note.

1. Increment will only work on numbers. It will fail on other data types
2. By default, some of these failures can be silent. MongoDB functions in "Fire & Forget" mode and it may not be throwing an exception.

Try running in "safe" mode to ensure that your updates are working correctly.

In your case this looks as follows:

```
$coll1->update(array("_id"=>$pid),array('$inc' => array("balance" => $credit)), array('safe'=>true));
```

Comment: >By default, some of these failures can be silent. This is exactly the problem. From my script it should have been an Integer. By using the safe mode I was able to pinpoint the issue that $inc does not work on "objects".

Comment: If this is the answer would you be able to "mark it as answered"?